# In OpenCV, What does the function CvSVM::predict() returns 0 imply?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to use the SVM included in the OpenCV library. I made two labels: either 1 or -1. However, sometimes the predict() function returns 0. (It works as expected sometimes, when testing cases are close to my training data, but fails when the testing case is far away or exactly same as my training data) My guess is that the data can't be separated linearly. I couldn't find any information online about what the function returns 0 implies.

Also, if I should try to use the method for non-linearly separable data. What should the settings be for CvSVMParams?

Thank you.

Optional information: I am working on color recognition. So my training cases are all the pixels from a sample photo. Since each pixel contains 3 data(RGB), my array is like arr[numOfPixels][3].

```
int main(void){
//read two source img for the training data
Mat color1 = imread("zi.png");
Mat color2 = imread("lv.png");

//mark 0-2499 to label 1 and 2500-5000 to label -1
float labels[5000] = {1.0};
for(int c=2500;c<5000;c++){
    labels[c] = -1.0;
}
Mat LabelsMat(5000,1,CV_32FC1,labels);


//get 5000 pixels training data
float trainingdata[5000][3] = {{0,0,0}};
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++){
        trainingdata[count][0] = (float)color1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        trainingdata[count][1] = (float)color1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
        trainingdata[count][2] = (float)color1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
        cout<<trainingdata[count][0]<<","<<trainingdata[count][1]<<","<<trainingdata[count][2]<<endl;
        count++;    
    }}

cout<<"green"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++){
        trainingdata[count][0] =(float)color2.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        trainingdata[count][1] =(float)color2.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
        trainingdata[count][2] =(float)color2.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
        cout<<trainingdata[count][0]<<","<<trainingdata[count][1]<<","<<trainingdata[count][2]<<endl;
        count++;        
    }}
Mat trainingDataMat(5000,3,CV_32FC1,trainingdata);

//sets SVM Parameters
CvSVMParams params;  
params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;  
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;  
params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);  

//train the SVM
CvSVM SVM;  
SVM.train(trainingDataMat, LabelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);  

//here's a quick test case
Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,3) << 70,43,65);
cout<<(float)SVM.predict(sampleMat);
system("pause");

//set up the full testcase
Mat testcase = imread("zi.png");
if(!testcase.data)system("pause");
cout<<"testcase"<<endl;
float testdata[900][3] = {{0,0,0}};
count =0;
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<30;j++){
        testdata[count][0]=(float)testcase.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        testdata[count][1]=(float)testcase.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
        testdata[count][2]=(float)testcase.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
        cout<<testdata[count][0]<<","<<testdata[count][1]<<","<<testdata[count][2]<<endl;
        count++;
    }}


//test the testcase
for(int i=0;i<900;i++){
float temp[3] = {50,50,50};
Mat sampleMat(1,3,CV_32FC1,temp);
cout<< SVM.predict(sampleMat)<<endl;
}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Post some code otherwise we can't simply guess where your problem is. For non-linearly separable data you could use `RBF` as the kernel type of the svm which is slower than `Linear` but could give better results.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You think "0-2499 to label 1 and 2500-5000 to label -1" but `labels` ends up with 0-2499 set to 0.0 and 2500-5000 set to -1.0. That's why you 're getting zeros later. Print the values of labels and see yourself.

Comment: Actually, only `labels[0]` will be set to `1.0`.

Comment: You 're probably confused because `float labels[5000] = {1.0};` initializes only the first one to `1.0` and everything else to `0.0`.

Comment: WOW! Thank you. I thought that way could initialize all elements at once, and apparently I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You can fill `labels` using a loop or `std::fill_n`.

Comment: Thanks! I used a loop, and now I see how convenient it is to use fill_n. :)